# referencing a google sheet linked table in bigquery through an app script doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script, scope, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-bigquery

I have a simple google sheet where data is updated on regular basis (say weekly, the previous week's data is deleted); I have declared this sheet as a table in bigquery and wrote a script in app script which takes data and append it to a static table with same structure (basically archiving);

Manually this works, however this never works through app script (using triggers); I read on internet, It require o-auth and scoping, however all my google sheets, bigquery credentials belong to me. Can anyone help me write scope/o-auth in my app script?

```
function saveQueryToTable() {
  var projectNumber = 'XXXX';
  var projectId = 'XXXX';
  var datasetId = 'YYYY';
  var tableId = 'archives';


  var job = {
    configuration: {

      query: {
        "allowLargeResults": true,
        query:'SELECT * FROM YYYY.temp_table_connected_to_a_google_sheet',
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
        },
        'writeDisposition':'WRITE_APPEND',
        'maximumBillingTier': '5'
      }
    }
  };


var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId);
Logger.log(queryResults.status);


}
```

tried declaring scopes a bit in script:-

//  scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery;
//scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';

//   return OAuth2.createService('drive')
etc

Comment: Notes: I have also enabled bigquery API, DRIVE API and Sheets API in console.

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Where does it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a call to a Google Drive API to initialise it before running your code.  For example:

```
//just a random call to activate the Drive API scope 
var test = Drive.Properties.list('....a folderid of a Drive folder you have access to....')
```

See this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905890) for more information

Comment: Great! Please can you mark this as the answer so others can find it easily in future...

Comment: Thanks. Done that. Have posted another question, Can you help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45476849/error-in-loading-csv-into-bigquery-from-app-script

Comment: Hi run_akhil, if Jon's answer helped you, consider also up voting it :)! Also, when you want to let someone know you've made a comment, make sure to add their name like "@JonClarke" otherwise they won't receive your message in their inbox.